# div won't expand height for floating contents

Tags: html, css

This question has been asked a bunch and I've looked at them all (seemingly).  I have a div with some floating content that won't expand to the size of the content.  I've added `clear:both` (to literally every possible line, which has effects, but doesn't solve it), and I've tried every permutation of `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` on pretty much every element in here.  Just for good measure I have also tried changing the divs to spans.

Whatever I do, if you make the window skinny enough eventually the buttons fall below the area of the div.  Why and how can I fix it?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncL5Lmjj/3/)

```css
.confirmation-modal {
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 4rem;
    max-height:18rem;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:5px;
    
}


.confirmation-raised-panel{
    background-color: #ffed83;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 4rem; /* Full height */
    max-height:18rem;    
        overflow: auto;
}

.buttons{
  float:right;
}

.confirmation-message {
    overflow: auto;
  margin: 20px 0 0 30px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  float:left;
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmation-modal">
    <div class="confirmation-raised-panel">
        <div class="confirmation-message">
            This is a big message that takes up a bunch of space.  Yes indeed.  Do you like it?
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="buttons">        
                <button>Yes, I'm Sure</button>
                <button>Cancel</button>
            </div>
                <br class="clear"/>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have `height: 4rem;` in the outer two containers - this prevents them from getting any higher. Delete that or make that `min-height`, and you are all set:

```css
.confirmation-modal {
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  min-height: 4rem;
  max-height: 18rem;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.confirmation-raised-panel {
  background-color: #ffed83;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 4rem;
  max-height: 18rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.buttons {
  float: right;
}

.confirmation-message {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 20px 0 0 30px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmation-modal">
  <div class="confirmation-raised-panel">
    <div class="confirmation-message">
      This is a big message that takes up a bunch of space. Yes indeed. Do you like it?
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Yes, I'm Sure</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <br class="clear" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed height for your modal (`height: 4rem`), he can't expand.

```css
.confirmation-modal {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffed83;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.confirmation-message {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons{
  float: right;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmation-modal">
  <p class="confirmation-message">This is a big message that takes up a bunch of space. Yes indeed. Do you like it?</p>
  <div class="buttons">        
    <button>Yes, I'm Sure</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```